# Как на php создать такой json?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Нужно на основе данных из базы MySQL создать json такого вида:

```
{
   "draw": 1,
   "recordsTotal": 57,
   "recordsFiltered": 57,
   "data": [
 [
   "Airi",
   "Satou",
   "Accountant",
   "Tokyo",
   "28th Nov 08",
   "$162,700"
 ],
 [
   "Angelica",
   "Ramos",
   "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
   "London",
   "9th Oct 09",
   "$1,200,000"
  ]
 ]
}
```

Покуда не совсем понял как это сделать.

Думаю для начала нужно создать массив, что у меня тоже не получается:

```
$json = array();

$option_while = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($option_while)) {
    $json[$item['id']] = $item['login'];
}
```

Как делать правильно? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: создаете такой массив $arr = [ 'draw'=>1, 'data'=> [ [ 'Airi', 'Satou' ], [ 'Angelica', 'Angelica' ] ] ] и затем json_encode

Comment: @Jean-Claude как создать такой массив в цикле? с данными из базы?

Comment: сделайте print_r(json_decode($str, true)) и увидите, какой структуры ммассив вам нужен

Comment: как как, берете и формируете его, одни данные в data, другие в draw, третьи в recordsTotal и так далее, это же не одной строкой делается

Comment: Версия MySQL? Если 5,7,8 или свежее - получайте оттуда сразу в JSON и не занимайтесь ерундой. да и если старее - опять-таки на MySQL получайте сразу нужный JSON-текст, используя GROUP_CONCAT() и CONCAT(), и не строгайте [censored]код...

Comment: @Akina "строгать", все равно, придется, судя по структуре массива - такой нерегулярный формат я не представляю, как получить

Comment: *такой нерегулярный формат я не представляю, как получить* да нет там ничего сложного... подмассивы что в `data:`, собираются CONCAT()-ом в подзапросе, сливаются вместе GROUP_CONCAT()-ом, а потом CONCAT()-ятся с остальными полями таблицы и соотв. обвязкой. Да, монстрообразненько будет, но исключительно в тексте, а не в выполнении.

Comment: фу-фу-фу :) уж точно лучше строгать

Answer (score 2):

Я вам набросал заготовку, а там уж по месту подправьте

```
$json = array();

$option_while = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($option_while)) {
    $json[] = array_values($item);
}

$json = [ "draw" => 1, "recordsTotal" => 57, "recordsFiltered" => 57, 'data' => $json ];
echo json_encode($json)
```

Comment: Надо учитывать, что одна таблица в показанном тексте/коде - голимый фэйк. Там минимум две таблицы - блок `data:` явно собирается. И товарищ весьма очевидно желает по значениям из полученного по первой таблице набора данных выдёргивать по одной записи из другой таблицы и стыковать в результат...

Comment: @Akina да, согласен, ничего про происхождение массивов непонятно, поэтому я и не рассматривал это как ответ, просто в комментарии неудобно